# Timer Control in .NET Windows Application

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, intervals

I have a desktop application running for the below process, currently client had asked a desktop application developed in VB.NET 2010, later the same will need to convert to windows service app

Process is: I have a process of mail check and do certain transaction according to content on every mail.

I have to keep checking if I received any mail and if the mail is received I need to do certain transaction in backend with database. Time taken to do such determined time and is also appreciated by client.

Step of Business Transaction Process as as follows:

```
1. Get the list of all mail from the mail server and store all mail locally to server

2. There is loop for steps 2.1 to 2.5
2.1. Start Processing mail content reading
2.2. Process the mail Content
2.3. Complete the process
2.4. Next Mail
2.5. No Mail come out of the Loop
```

Mail Process time for single mail is around minimum is 10 Seconds to maximum is 12 Seconds

Now the question is the process of new mail check should be automated after X interval for which i planned to use Timer Control.

```
1) I want to know the actual workflow of timer control.
2) Is it good to use timer control, if not what can be the best option?
3) Timer Control should not start the next process before my earlier process is complete.
```

Comment: Firstly, if you have to build a Windows app now and convert to a Windows service later then make sure that you put the bulk of the functionality into one or more DLL projects so that you can simply reuse them as is.

Comment: As for your question, it's not a question for this site.  SO is about specific issues with code that you've written.  If you haven't written any code then you shouldn't be asking questions here.  Try this other Stack Exchange site instead: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @jmcilhinney when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat, I did say "instead" but fair point, I didn't make it clear that the existing question should be deleted if a new one was created.  That said, I rather expected this question to be voted closed rather quickly.

Comment: What made you think it was a good idea to format numbered lists as code blocks?